# Objective-C return nil inside init

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I have a model for example Product. Product has required property id.
So I thought that model can't be without property.
My implementation of init method for Product class.

```
- (instancetype)initWithProductId:(NSNumber *)productId {
    if ([productId integerValue] <= 0) {
       return nil;
    }
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _productId = productId;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is it legal to return nil inside initilization methods? Will I get memory management problems?
And could some one explain why it's legal and when I should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost. Obviously someone has called alloc to create an unitialised object, and is now calling your init method. With your code, the super class init will not be called. When the object is deallocated, the super class dealloc is called. But that might fail if superclass init was never called, depending on the implementation of your superclass. So the correct way would be:

```
if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
    if (productId.integerValue <= 0)
        return nil;
    _productId = productId;
}
return self;
```

Comment: I test this situation. And I see that `dealloc` method is executed if return nil, before `[super init]`. But I also asked is it right way to return nil inside `init` method if object can't anything without `productId` (like in example)